# .htaccess allow download on cookies is set

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies, setcookie

How  to set .htaccess to detect a Cookie and allow to download files from Site directories?
I use a command `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*pswdcookie.*$ [NC]` to detect that cookies.
The "pswdcookies" is generated by [Simple Authorization Script:SAS](http://www.zann-marketing.com/sas/)

The problem is, if user accesses the file directly, he can download it, even if he is not authorized. But i need to allow direct link accessing only to user which have Cookies with name "pswdcookies" where I store the MD5 hash of the password.

Comment: Can't you just put a PHP script there to serve the files, and put the files somewhere that is not directly accessible? Makes life a lot easier... If you want them to look like direct links just do a rewrite rule something like `RewriteRule ^download/(.*)$ download.php?file=$1 [L]`

Comment: no is not a reason... I do this for a group of users who have a password and the password is encrypted in cookies

`$data=array( // Insert data in format 'UserName:Password
'demo:demo');`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying there...

Comment: Security risk here my friend.